# Why does my metafile "lose" a bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawing, metafile

Recently I found a bug while drawing stuff with metafiles. Right now I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if there is a bug within the drawing of metafiles itself:

While drawing images on a metafile which is drawn on another metafile itself by PlayEnhMetafile I lose images far down or to the right. I guess it has something to do with screen coordinates (I run dual screen 1280*1024, so 2560*1024), 'cause the bottom lane where the images begin to vanish is around 500.

Here is some example-code I created to show you the problem more specifically. (You can just replace the Form1.cs of a freshly created Windows C# project with this code and place a button on it)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MetaFileDrawing
{ 
 public partial class Form1
  : Form
 { 
  [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern bool PlayEnhMetaFile(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hEmf, ref Rectangle rectangle);

  [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hGdiObj);

  public Form1()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates the sub-metafile where the actual drawing is done (and the problems occur).
  /// </summary>
  private Metafile GetSubMetafile()
  {
   Metafile metafile = null;
   using(Graphics controlGraphics = this.CreateGraphics())
   {
    using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
     metafile = new Metafile(memoryStream, controlGraphics.GetHdc(), EmfType.EmfOnly, string.Empty);

     using(Graphics metafileGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(metafile))
     {
      Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Fibonacci.png");
      // Draw the image 3 times... if pushed to far down, it wont show up?
      metafileGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Yellow, new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 1200));
      metafileGraphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));
      metafileGraphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(10, 950));
      metafileGraphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(20, 1150));
     }
    }
    controlGraphics.ReleaseHdc();
   }
   return metafile;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates and draws the metafile.
  /// </summary>
  private void DrawMetafile()
  {
   using(Graphics controlGraphics = this.CreateGraphics())
   {    
    using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
     // EmfType.EmfOnly is a restriction defined by my project limitations
     Metafile metafile = new Metafile(memoryStream, controlGraphics.GetHdc(), EmfType.EmfOnly, string.Empty);

     using(Graphics metafileGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(metafile))
     {
      // A large red rect for orientation
      metafileGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, 4000, 4000));

      // Create the sub metafile
      Metafile subMetafile = GetSubMetafile();

      // To check, draw the subMetafile with DrawImage (works fine, the inlined image is drawn 3 times)
      metafileGraphics.DrawImage(subMetafile, new Point(10, 0));

      // On the right side, draw the sub metafile using PlayEnhMetaFile (dont work correctly, only 2 images)
      IntPtr hMetafile = subMetafile.GetHenhmetafile();
      Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(100, 0, 170, 1230);
      PlayEnhMetaFile(metafileGraphics.GetHdc(), hMetafile, ref rectangle1);
      metafileGraphics.ReleaseHdc();
      DeleteObject(hMetafile);
     }

     metafile.Save("Output.emf");
    }
    controlGraphics.ReleaseHdc();
   }
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   DrawMetafile();
  }
 }
}
```

As you can see, using the PlayEnhMetaFile function causes me to lose one of the three images. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using C++, and found two workarounds. I could use GDI+ to attach to the metafile and play it, but the coordinates were slightly off. The more complicated alternative which I am currently using is using EnumEnhMetaFile, and manually doing the bitblt/stretchblt/stretchdibits calls, this seems to work. If you found a better solution let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately I've hit the same issue using Delphi. It's a real, language-agnostic GDI bug.